# The pattern of `DirChangePre` is strange where it jumps between `global` and `tabpage`?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, lua

As title. I'm trying to fix my plugin with a problem related to the pattern of `autocmd`. I know that the event `DirChangedPre` brings a pattern with it when it happens. To reproduce the strange thing I just observed, you can do these steps:

1. start Neovim, and call `:cd path/to/my/config`.
2. create a new tab by `:tabnew` and run `:tcd ./subfolder/`. This creates an event `DirChangedPre` with a pattern `tabpage`.
3. jump back to the first tab with `:tabp`. This creates an event `DirChangedPre` with a pattern `global`.

While I expect that 3. would also have a pattern `tabpage`. Why it gives `global`? I didn't call `cd` again.

I only tested this on Neovim.

Comment: I suspect the reasoning is that, in the first and original tabpage, the working directory is still the "global" working directory. (That is, that tabpage does not have a tabpage-specific working directory, so it keeps the global one.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think that's the answer :) Sorry that I have no time to see your comment while I was asking so I have posted an *answer* myself. Can I make a conclusion that: every time I jump to tabpage, which I haven't called `tcd`(nor `lcd` on the window my cursor at) on it, then internally (neo)vim will run a `cd` for it to recover my current-directory?

Comment: I'm not precisely certain. You could probably check the relevant source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reasoning by @D. Ben Knoble in the comment section of my OP is correct:

> I suspect the reasoning is that, in the first and original tabpage, the working directory is still the "global" working directory. (That is, that tabpage does not have a tabpage-specific working directory, so it keeps the global one.)
> – D. Ben Knoble ♦ Dec 15, 2022 at 16:00

---

You can detect this `global`-`cd` on `:tabn` and `:tabp` by the `vim.v.event` variable and do your `tabpage`-`cd` stuff there: (the second param of `nvim_create_autocmd`)

```lua
{
pattern = 'global',
callback = function()
  if vim.v.event.changed_window -- this will be `false` on both `:tabp`,`:tabn`.
    then
    -- ...
  end
end
}
```